# Is there a way to use OLE DB Provider for Jet on an unsaved Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, oledb, jet

I am working with the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet to execute queries on spreadsheets in Excel using VBA. Is there a way to execute the following code on an *unsaved* workbook?

For example, `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` returns "Book1" if the workbook has never been saved. In that case the Data Source will assume the path is the active directory, and error out because the file was never saved.

Is there any way to use the Excel temporary file as the Data Source for Jet? I would like to test this but I don't even know how to return the Path and Name for the Excel temporary file.

```
Public Sub LocalJetQuery()

    Dim objStartingRange As Range
    Dim objConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim objRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strDSN As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set objStartingRange = Application.Selection

    If CLng(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
        strDSN = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
        & "Data Source=" & objStartingRange.Worksheet.Parent.FullName & ";" _
        & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"
    Else
        strDSN = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
        & "Data Source=" & objStartingRange.Worksheet.Parent.FullName & ";" _
        & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"
    End If

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & objStartingRange.Worksheet.Name & "$];"

    objConnection.Open strDSN
    objRecordset.Open strSQL, objConnection

    Application.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset objRecordset

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you running this from? Excel itself? If so, you might be able to do what you need via automating Excel itself, i.e., in VBA code. I'm an Access developer, so can't tell you how it's done, but via VBA you can deal with the data in the state it's in loaded into an instance of Excel, regardless of whether it's been saved to disk.

Comment: Yeah, inside Excel. I want to run SQL queries on data in spreadsheets, but I don't want to have to save the workbook beforehand.

Comment: I don't see any way to run a SQL query on unsaved data. That doesn't mean you can't look at the data and use Excel's capabilities to accomplish much the same thing. Have you looked into automating the filtering feature? You might be able to do a simple filter and check total fields that way. But it would be a lot simpler to just save the spreadsheet (or a copy of it as a temp file for querying purposes!).

Comment: I hadn't thought of automating filter functionality. I'll look into it. I have also found that Jet doesn't have the same limitations as Excel spreadsheets, which brings up other issues. It's simpler to stay within Excel functionality when working within Excel, but I'll leave the question up. Maybe someone will come up with a work around. Thanks David!

Comment: can you just save the new workbook as a temp file, then delete the excel file after your done w/ it?

your code looks like its just making a new workbook and dumping your query in that new workbook.  you could just dump your query to a new page within your current workbook if your not going to save it?  Then do your other manipulations, then delete that temporary sheet.  Not really sure what your trying to accomplish...

Comment: @Fink: that was just a test to see if I could run a simple query on an unsaved workbook. Dumping it to another workbook was a different test. If I was going to use a temp file to run Jet queries I would just copy it outright. CopyFromRecordset seems to have problems with large ranges. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just like David Fenton says in the comments.

Comment: @MarkJ: forgot this was unanswered. Thanks!

Comment: I find this hard to believe because the interface is implemented (many implementations actually) and also very useful. Is this still a correct answer as of 2014?

Comment: @PatrickFromberg Not sure which interface you are referring to. I don't know for sure whether this is still a correct answer (but I suspect it is). If anyone else out there knows, maybe they could post and let us know?